# hibernate sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush() doesn't work for tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testng

I use following tecnologies:

- TestNG(6.9.10)
- Spring(4.3.2.RELEASE)
- Hibernate(5.1.0.Final)
- Java 8

I test some code with functionality by integration tests and i need to check the entity for correct save/update/delete or any other changes. There are **sessionFactory** configuration in my **.xml** :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:hibernateProperties="jdbcProperties">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.package"/>
</bean>
```

and test class example:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml",
    "classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml",
    "classpath:/applicationContext-orm.xml"})
public class AccountServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Autowired
private SomeService someService;
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Test
public void updateEntity() {
    //given
    Long entityId = 1L;
    SomeClass expected = someService.get(entityId);
    String newPropertyValue = "new value";
    //when
    someService.changeEntity(entity, newPropertyValue);
    // Manual flush is required to avoid false positive in test
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    //then
    expected = someService.get(entityId);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected.getChangedProperty() , newPropertyValue);
}
```

service method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public int changeEntity(entity, newPropertyValue) {
    return dao().executeNamedQuery(REFRESH_ACCESS_TIME_QUERY,
            CollectionUtils.arrayToMap("id", entity.getId(), "myColumn", newPropertyValue));
}
```

dao:

```
@Override
public int executeNamedQuery(final String query, final Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    Query queryObject = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(query);
    if (parameters != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            NamedQueryUtils.applyNamedParameterToQuery(queryObject, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return queryObject.executeUpdate();
}
```

But my entity property didn't change after flush()

as described here, [change @Autowire SessionFactory with @PersistenceContext EntityManager](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9032) , i should use `EntityManager` to `flush()` - but i can't do this - i can't transform `sessionFactory` to `EntityManager`, and i don't need in creation of `EntityManager` for my application - because i need to change my **.xml** config file and others.

Is there are any another solutions of this problem?

Comment: What isn't working? Using an `EntityManager` or `SessionFactory` shouldn't make a difference. Add your service and dao to your post.

Comment: To me `EntityManager` has more in common with `Session` then with `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Correct. But using plain hibernate or the JPA abstraction and flushing one of those shouldn't matter. Hence the request for additional information on what isn't working and more code.

Comment: Actually your code is working as expected. The problem is you aren't using hibernate as you should. You are bypassing hibernate and directly updating values in the database. Your value in the datbase has changed BUT as your test method is transactional, the entity is still in the first level cache. When getting an entity by id, and already present it will be returned as is, it will not be retrieved from the database again. This all has to do with how you are working around hibernate instead of using hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working as expected.

Your test method is transactional and thus your `Session` is alive during the whole execution of the test method. The `Session` is also the 1st level cache for hibernate and when loading an entity from the database it is put into the session.

So the line `SomeClass expected = someService.get(entityId);` will load the entity from the database and with it also put it in the `Session`.

Now this line `expected = someService.get(entityId);` first checks (well actually the dao method underneath) checks if the entity of the requested type with the id is already present in the `Session` if so it simply returns it. It will **not** query the database!.

The main problem is that you are using hibernate in a wrong way, you are basically bypassing hibernate with the way you are updating your database. You should update your entity and persist it. You should not write queries to update the database!

*Annotated test method*

```
@Test
public void updateEntity() {
    //given
    Long entityId = 1L;
    SomeClass expected = someService.get(entityId); // load from db and put in Sesion
    String newPropertyValue = "new value";
    //when
    someService.changeEntity(entity, newPropertyValue); // update directly in database bypass Session and entity
    // Manual flush is required to avoid false positive in test
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    //then
    expected = someService.get(entityId); // return entity from Session
    Assert.assertEquals(expected.getChangedProperty() , newPropertyValue);
}
```

To only fix the test add a call to `clear()` after the `flush()`.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
```

However what you actually should do is stop writing code like that and use Hibernate and persistent entities in the correct way.

```
@Test
public void updateEntity() {
    //given
    Long entityId = 1L;
    String newPropertyValue = "new value";

    SomeClass expected = someService.get(entityId); 
    expected.setMyColumn(newPropertyValue);

    //when
    someService.changeEntity(entity); 

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

    // now you should use a SQL query to verify the state in the DB. 
    Map<String, Object> dbValues = getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap("select * from someClass where id=?", entityId);
    //then
    Assert.assertEquals(dbValues.get("myColumn"), newPropertyValue);
}
```

Your dao method should look something like this.

```
public void changeEntity(SomeClass entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
}
```

Comment: as i found out - if i don't invoke service method and change value directly through setter - i just use update() and all is fine - i can get entity again(from cache - because transaction is not committed) and i'll see changed property, and i shouldn't use flush() for this. But problem is than i have a named query within my service method and it invokes executeUpdate() for Query queryObject

Comment: Have you actually read my comment and answer? I gave the answer for BOTH options. Nonetheless updating things with a query is just wrong in a hibernate environment. But again READ my answer instead of only the last part.

Comment: Thanks, adding a `.clear()` call did the trick for me when flushing alone wouldn't help.